# How can get authenticated user role from pivot table via Vue JS in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hi I'm trying to get the role of the authenticated user. I have 3 tables: Users, Roles and role-user(pivot). With many to many relationship(see below). When I call `v-if="$gate.isSuperAdmin()` in vue component it's giving an error:

> "TypeError: this.user.roles is undefined"

```
**User Model
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

**Role Model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

---

```
** App.blade.php(master layout)
  <body>

<div id="app"></div>
  @auth
    <script>
        window.user = @json(auth()->user()) 
        //window.user = @json(auth::user()->roles) (I tried this as well)
    </script>   
  @endauth

<script src="{{ mix('/b_assets/entry-point.js') }}"></script>
```

```
** Gate.js
export default class Gate{

constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
}

  isAdmin() {
     return this.user.slug === 'admin';
  }

  isSuperAdmin() {
    return this.user.roles.slug === 'superadmin';
  }  
}
```

Then in App.js I import the Gate.js

```
/ Get Authenticated User
 import Gate from '@/Gate';
 Vue.prototype.$gate = new Gate(window.user);
```

Comment: try and print `auth()->user()->roles` in blade and see the output. Also check `this.user` in Vue developer toolbar and check the error message.

Comment: @MikeRoss, auth()->user()->roles gives output the current user role(s), which is correct. But how can call the user role in my Gate.js file?

Comment: Try and just `console.log(this.user.roles)` and see if roles are printed correctly first. Attache the console output format.

Comment: @MikeRoss, I called window.user = @json(auth()->user()->roles) window.user = @json(auth()->user()->roles) zzzz

Answer (score 1):

Check the following things

1) `User.php` your model file and make sure it has the `roles` relation loaded.

```
protected $with = ['roles']
```

Print in console `user` data and see that `roles` have been loaded.

2) You have a typo on  `isAdmin()` code

```
isAdmin() {
     //return this.user.slug === 'admin'; 
     return this.user.roles.slug === 'admin';
}
```

This should work fine.

Comment: you are amazing. I was able to get the role of the user. However, I will have to call for example return this.user.roles[0].slug. Sometimes user may have multiple roles. Instead of specify the array index, how can loop through to find  the role passed in the condition?

Comment: you can create a method in vue to loop through the roles or do it on php side and send the flags attached with user model. for example if user is super admin check on the php side and append the flag for each role with the user data.